# How to give inputs in JWT Console App from tomcat?

Tags: java, docusignapi

i downloaded JWT Console App from code-example-java.

It works well when i give the inputs from the console, but I want to be able to give these inputs of (signerName, signerEmail, ccName, ccEmail) from localhost(tomcat).

How can I do this?

Ps: I need to be able to send for signing a document from my java web app, thats why I tried with JWT api.

Answer (score 0):

For JWT the quickstart shows a console app
For Auth Code Grant - the quickstart shows a web app
There's no problem using JWT with web app, for that I would pick the big/full quickstart (right-most) which is a web app including both auth types and all code examples.

If you don't want to do this, you'll have to still have a web app and use the code you downloaded.

The relevant code inside [JWTConsoleApp.java](https://github.com/docusign/code-examples-java/blob/master/JWT%20Console%20App/src/main/java/com/docusign/JWTConsoleApp.java) to do what you want is:

```
// Send envelope
apiClient.addDefaultHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);
EnvelopesApi envelopesApi = new EnvelopesApi(apiClient);
EnvelopeSummary results = envelopesApi.createEnvelope(accountId, envelope);
System.out.println("Successfully sent envelope with envelopeId " + results.getEnvelopeId());
```